# Not able to parse JavaScript in Identity Server 4 .Net CORE 3.1 MVC - Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, identityserver4

I have a .Net Core MVC Application for Identity Server 4. Inside of the Login.cshtml file I have a script tag surrounding 37k lines of a compiled function from a React application. I am trying to render this function inside of the .Net Core application. The function works in other instances -

- Regular HTML file
- Default .Net Core MVC application pulled from Windows directly
- In React .html index file

My thought is that I am missing a certain package to be able to correctly parse this code.

`((e = u.createElement("div")).innerHTML = "<script></script>")`

**Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token**

Now when I update  to document.createElement("script"), the console then returns another syntax error two lines down.

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'

Thank you for the help!

Comment: This looks a whole lot like your previous question just a little while ago.

Comment: You cannot have the string "</script>" in the middle of the body of an inline `<script>`.  You cannot have it inside a string literal of any sort; generally the approach is to break it into two parts: `"</scr" + "ipt>"`

Comment: ? (((e = u.createElement("div")).innerHTML = "<script></scr"+"ipt>")), If i do this - it then gives an error of the comma afterwards..Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ',' (at login:24361:90)

Comment: I have no idea what the overall problem is with your big `<script>` but that will work better than `"</script>"` in a string literal. The browser parsing the HTML markup does not know anything about JavaScript. It parses a `<script>` block by accumulating text blindly until it sees `</script>`.

Comment: You're going to have to provide *a lot* more detail. Nobody knows what's in that mystery 37K of script text.

Comment: The issue happened to be auto formatter..I'm not longer getting console errors, however the function is not producing the result I want, meaning the component I'm bringing in, is not displaying and the script is running..